# How to make private builder() method with lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I’m using [lombok @Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder). When I place `@Builder` annotation on the `MyExample` class, `@Builder` generates **public** `builder()` method. But I want to make **private** `builder()` method. Unfortunately `@Builder` annotation does not have `access` option. How should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can overwrite the generated builder method to make it private. As far as I know, that's the only way:

```
@Builder
public static class Foo<F, T> {

    // hide lombok's builder method:
    private static FooBuilder builder() {
        return new FooBuilder();
    }

}
```

However, this enables you to do some more advanced initialization of the builder. For example, you can initialize the builder with some defaults and also kickstart the builder with initial user-supplied values.

Here's an example:

```
@Builder
public static class Car {

    // kickstart builder method available to user
    public static CarBuilder builder(String brand, String model) {
        return builder().brand(brand).model(model);
    }

    // hide lombok's own builder method and apply some defaults:
    private static CarBuilder builder() {
        return new CarBuilder().color(System.getenv("DEFAULT_CAR_COLOR"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the annotation like this: `@Builder(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)`.

Comment: I don't think access is available on Builder ?

Comment: What you can do is make at least the builder _class_ private. `private static class MyExampleBuilder{}` While you define the class lombok will still generate the implementation. Clients can still access the builder() operation, but they won't be able to actually use returned builder object.

Comment: This answer is (now) actually the correct answer: `access` is available on `@Builder` from v1.18.8 per [docs](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder). The currently [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035425/885922) is still valid and most flexible approach but overkill if OP just wants to change scope of `builder()` only as asked